# Can't process data with azure stream analytics?

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm sending data to the event hub from the azure function with the following code.

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    const {  EventHubClient, EventData, EventPosition, OnMessage, OnError, MessagingError } = require("@azure/event-hubs");
    const connectionString = "Endpoint=connection string"
    const eventHubsName = "eventhub_2"
    var axios = require('axios')

    const client = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubsName);
    context.log('sssaaa')
    var response = await axios.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/nifty500StockWatch.json')
    await client.send(response['data']['data'])
    context.log('message sent')

};
```

I can able to send the data, but when I process it with Azure stream analytics I'm getting following

```
error:
No events found for 'NSEStockInput'.
Start time: Tuesday, September 24, 2019, 12:30:18 PM
End time: Tuesday, September 24, 2019, 12:33:18 PM
Last time arrival: Tuesday, September 24, 2019, 12:33:18 PM
Diagnostics: Source '<unknown_location>' had 1 occurrences of kind 'InputDeserializerError.InvalidData' between processing times '2019-09-24T07:03:22.9492042Z' and '2019-09-24T07:03:22.9492042Z'. Json input stream should either be an array of objects or line separated objects. Found token type: Null
```

'InputDeserializerError.InvalidData' means here it serialize the data, so I need to send data in deserialized way, but client.send or client.batch can accept only the JSON object typed data.
This is sample JSON that's being sent to the event hub.

```
[ { symbol: 'ALLCARGO',
    open: '106.90',
    high: '114.90',
    low: '106.70',
    ltP: '109.75',
    ptsC: '8.60',
    per: '8.50',
    trdVol: '8.20',
    trdVolM: '0.82',
    ntP: '9.03',
    mVal: '0.09',
    wkhi: '124.45',
    wklo: '87.15',
    wkhicm_adj: '357.70',
    wklocm_adj: '102.00',
    xDt: '31-DEC-2999',
    cAct: '-',
    previousClose: '101.15',
    dayEndClose: '-',
    iislPtsChange: '8.60',
    iislPercChange: '8.50',
    yPC: '3.98',
    mPC: '19.55' },
  { symbol: 'IDBI',
    open: '30.80',
    high: '33.80',
    low: '30.40',
    ltP: '33.25',
    ptsC: '2.30',
    per: '7.43',
    trdVol: '132.04',
    trdVolM: '13.20',
    ntP: '43.01',
    mVal: '0.43',
    wkhi: '65.75',
    wklo: '23.65',
    wkhicm_adj: '116.40',
    wklocm_adj: '52.90',
    xDt: '09-AUG-2019',
    cAct: 'ANNUAL GENERAL MEETING',
    previousClose: '30.95',
    dayEndClose: '-',
    iislPtsChange: '2.30',
    iislPercChange: '7.43',
    yPC: '-36.91',
    mPC: '18.54' }]
```

[image: error message screen shot]

[image: stream analytics input]

It works fine when I use below code with event hub as out bind in azure function
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var axios = require('axios')
    var response = await axios.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/nifty500StockWatch.json')
    // var sendBatchData = {body:response['data']['data'],partitionKey:"pk12345"}
    // context.log(response['data']['data'])
    // sample = [{'name':'saran'},{'name':'jeeva'}]
    return JSON.stringify(response['data']['data'])

};

Comment: Can you post an example of the json payload you are sending to the event hub?

Comment: @Peter Bon you can see my updated question

Comment: May I know where the error message shows ? In the logs area of your azure function(send) ?

Comment: Now that error message is shown at Azure stream analytics side?

Comment: Did you choose "JSON" at the selection box of "Event serialization format" in Stream analytics ? And could you please show the screenshot of the error message and the screenshot of your stream analytics ?

Comment: So you got this error message when you click "save" in "Input details" box(during "testing input" after you click "save") ?

Comment: no, it will not show any error while any test connection or something this error happens only at the time data processing. it means json serialization  happens on JSON data not on string in json format.

Comment: see my updated question @Hury shen

Comment: @Hury shen, please see the updated question. Yes, I chose JSON and I know where the error is since stream analytics serialize input into JSON, so before sending it I need to deserialize it, means JSON.stringify(input JSON data), but azure event hub show me the error as Exception: Error: data is required and it must be of type object.

Comment: any idea guys. If get code for multiple send and batch send to event hub from azure function output bind, I'm OK with that

Comment: Recent error message says "Should be array of objects or line separated objects, got null". Is it possible that you are sending something like this [ {..}, {..}, null] ? If so, remove the null and change it to [{..}, {..}]

Comment: ya, but it's from the event hub, if you process the data from the stream analytics services, I need to serialize the incoming data so, we need to give the data in deserialized format i.e JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: If you just want to get the data send to event hub and use the data, the "Receive events" is also a solution. Can your needs be realized through "Receive events", you may refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-node-get-started-send#receive-events) tutorial.